# Rename a group of .txt files based on content that appears after a specific string in the text file?

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with hundreds of text files in it.  The file names have zero meaning.  I am trying to extract a variable number that appears after a string in each file and and rename the files using it.  I'm somewhat of a Powershell newbie (an old timer form the DOS world) but I have written many useful scripts with it.  I've searched high an low, this one has me stumped.

Any and all suggestions are welcome, or I'd happily pay someone for the snippet of code.  -Ed

Comment: You will likely need some sort of looping mechanic. You can use `Get-ChildItem` to query your folder for .txt files. You can pipe those results to `Foreach-Object {}`. Inside of your `foreach`, you can use `Get-Content` to read each file and pipe to `Where-Object {}` to find the target line(s) in the files or pipe to `Select-String` to find the target line(s). `Rename-Item` works well for renaming files. `Select-String` by itself can read files and output lines, matched text, and the filename of the read file.

Comment: This site is not a code writing service. People here help with specific coding issues like syntax problems, logic flow, etc. for a specific code snippet.